# How to find inode number using "find" command?

Tags: find, inode

How do you find the inode number of the name of files that start with a particular keyword like "test"?

We'll assume that there are files called: test, test1, test2.

Answer (score 10):

Try doing this (requires `cygwin` or such):

```
find . -type f -name 'test*' -printf '%p %i\n'
```

See

```
man find | less +/'-printf format'
```

Notes :

- `%p` stands for *file path*
- `%i` stands for *inode number*

Comment: +1 for not parsing `ls` output

Comment: When using a BSD system, GNU `find` must be installed.
E.g. in FreeBSD `pkg install findutils` then use `gfind`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this with find.

```
find . -iname 'test*' -type f -exec ls -i {} \;
```

`find` : the find command
`.` : the directory to search
`-iname 'test*'` : search for anything that matches test* regardless of case
`-type f` : only look for files
`-exec ls -i {} \;` : execute ls -i on each file found

```
find . -iname 'test*' -type f -printf '%i %f\n'
```

`find` : the find command
`.` :  the directory to search
`-iname 'test*'` :  search for anything that matches test* regardless of case
`-type f` :  only look for files
`-printf '%i %f\n'` -  print the inode, then the file's name only (no directories), and separate each file by a newline

Notes:

- Substitute `-iname` for `-name` if you want to be case sensitive.
- Substitute `.` with the absolute path if you want to search anything other than the current working directory.
- Substitute `%f` with `%p` for the file's name, including the path (differs whether you use relative or absolute paths in your find command).
- If you would like to be selective in your directories, don't forget the parameters `-prune` and `-depth`
- You can be more specific with your string and do something like `'test[0-9]'` to find everything test0-test9, or `'test[0-9]*'` for anything with the string "test", then one digit,  anything after that.